# Proper ways to Put XML into HBase

Tags: xml, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hbase

I am trying to put into HBase (version 1.1.X) some XML files stored locally.

My goal is to store the content of those XMLs in my HBase Table as string using MapReduce (**no reduce stage**) without loading them to HDFS.

Here is my pseudo-code:

```
fetchXMLs(path);
XML2OneLineFile();
configureHBase(); // + establishing connection
Map(input, output); //input: one XML file in one line; output : is the Put() of HBase;
closeConnection();
```

Is this way of tackling the problem correct, or there are better ways to do it?

ps: I do not want to parse or extract data from my XML, just store them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hbase is not really made for **large object storing**. Depending on the size of your XML, HBase might not be the solution you are looking for.

At this moment, I am working on a database consisting of multiple file types including XML. What I thought was good was to store any files under 1MB to HBase, and the rest to Hadoop, maintaining meta data either in an SQL or in HBase.

It depends a lot of what you want to achieve with this data.

Comment: indeed, my XMLs are not big at all but numerous ; in other terms I will have to store a lot of small size XML (about 90.000 files varying from 80KB to 500KB) in a short period of time.

Comment: then Hbase should be alright, if you don't need to scan the content of these files, it is alright to just dump the content in a column attributes. However, it will slow your scans (as it will have to scan all the content of each file). How do you need to access the data?

Comment: data will be accessed by targeted gets to particular ( rarely all) records in my Hbase Table. So is the idea of not loading files into HDFS still correct ?

Comment: yeah I guess so. I haven't done extensive tests with it so I can't tell if you loose a lot of performance by doing that. But if you only do gets it should be fine this way.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing XML string to Hbase, you can store them as byte[] 
and you can retrieve it back as an object( of serialized type) using deserialization.

You can do that in below way using Apache commons API.

For ex :

```
byte[] xmlInBytes = org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.serialize(Serializable obj)
```

for deserializing, you can do this

```
static Object deserialize(byte[] objectData)
```

if Object may be `w3c` document, object should be typecasted to w3c document.

I have already tested with many type of objects not only XML. 
It should work in the same way. Hope this helps.